# IHttpActionResult timeout while waiting for for powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, timeout

I need to do something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult StartArchiving(string machineName)
{
    //Email users to notice them an archiving started on their machine 
    EmailHelper.SendEmail(some params);

    //powershell scripting call could extends up to 2-3 hours maybe
    var answere = PowerShell.Archive(machineName);

    //Email users to notice them the archiving has stopped on their machine
    EmailHelper.SendEmail(some params);
}
```

After sending the first email, the task can last very long.
After finishing the Powershell script, the C# task will be still on and will send the second email or the task will be stopped and no email will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to execute your Powershell.Archive() call "asynchronously", which means that the rest of your code will continue running immediately without waiting on Powershell.Archive() to finish.  I would recommend reading up on how to do asynchronous programming using the "async" and "await" keywords in C#.